# Why does FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived() not getting called?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my android project I'm including Firebase Cloud Messaging. I'm on SDK 21 (Android 5).

My Intention is to override the `onMessageReceived()` method of `MyFirebaseMessagingService` to catch the method sent by Firebase and create my own notification.

But it seems like `onMessageReceived` doesn't get called anyway. I followed the built-in instructions from Android Studio to implement firebase and testing with the firebase console does actually send a message received by my test devices.

So my question is, did I forgot to implement something? I have my custom `FirebaseMessagingService`, a `BroadcastReceiver` to implement actions in notifications and an `Application`class that creates and handles the notification channels for SDKs >= 26.

This is a part of my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name=".Networking.Firebase.FireBaseApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <service android:name=".Networking.Firebase.PushMessageService" />
    <receiver android:name=".Networking.Firebase.PushReceiver"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage?) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)

            //TODO  Your Code

        }
    }
}


<!-- Firebase Notifications Service -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!--
     Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
        <!--
             Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
             notification message. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two service extends 
1. FirebaseMessagingService
2. FirebaseInstanceIdService

and in manifest

```
<service
    android:name="yourClassExtendsFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END firebase_service] -->
<!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
<service android:name="yourClassExtendsFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService needs to refresh token.
On Android O and above need to ask premisen run an app when it closes on some devices.

Comment: My IDE says, that FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated. Is there already an alternative?